# Wordpress Display Child Term of the Current Category Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Hi I am trying to display the child term of the current post category page.
However I can figure out what am missing here. Thanks

```
<?php
$current_tax = get_query_var( 'category' );
$current_term = get_queried_object()->term_id;

$child_terms = get_terms( array('category' => $current_tax,
                                'child_of' => $current_term,
                                'orderby' => 'name' ));
if ( ! empty( $child_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $child_terms ) ) {

    echo '<div class="post-index__cate">';
    foreach( $child_terms as $child ) {


        printf( '<a class="category-name" href="%s">', get_term_link( $child, $child->taxonomy ));

        echo $child->name. '</a>';

    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the taxonomy should be “category”, so your arguments for get_terms() should have “taxonomy” => “category”. $current_tax is irrelevant in this code then.